# regular expression that with negative look ahead

Tags: regex

i have a lot of lines like the following:

```
55, cpp: 1e+06,1e+06,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
56, cpp: 0.2342,0.2342,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
57, cpp: 1e+06,1e+06,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
58, cpp: 1e+06,0.2342,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
59, cpp: 3.453,3.453,    c:3.453,3.453,  ...
```

i want to filter those lines that contains `c:1e+06,1e+06` but not `cpp: 1e+06,1e+06`
in the example

```
56, cpp: 0.2342,0.2342,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
58, cpp: 1e+06,0.2342,    c:1e+06,1e+06,  ...
```

i tried something like `^\d+, cpp: (?!1e\+06,1e\+06),    c:1e\+06,1e\+06` but iam not very familiar with the look ahead things.

thank you in advance

Comment: c:1e\+06,1e\+06 should give you your result.there's no need for lookaheads

Comment: @vks how it gives the result?

Comment: For NOT ^((?!1e+06,1e+06.)*$ and for the YES one (?:c:1e+06,1e+06).Something like that?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/20

Comment: @vks what do you want to show? i have the lines in the first blocks and want a regex what only matches the lines that are in the second block

Comment: @vlad_tepesch did you see the regex?It matches second block only.What different you want to achieve?

Comment: @vks he wants to match the whole line where `c:1e+06,1e+06,` is present and `cpp: 1e+06,1e+06,` isn't present on the same line.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch you can use search instead of match  :)

Comment: @vks *facepalm* you are right `grep "c:1e+06,1e+06," | grep -v "cpp: 1e+06,1e+06,"` also would have done the job - sometimes things are too obvious ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses negative lookahead.

```
^(?:(?!cpp:\s*1e\+06,1e\+06).)*c:1e\+06,1e\+06.*$
```

OR

```
^\d+, (?:(?!cpp:\s*1e\+06,1e\+06).)*c:1e\+06,1e\+06.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/19)

**OR**

```
^(?:(?!cpp:\s*1e\+06,1e\+06).)*c:1e\+06,1e\+06(?:(?!cpp:\s*1e\+06,1e\+06).)*$
```